# set datepicker kendo ui, java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, datepicker, kendo-ui

I try to set 2 datepickers with a click event.

my code looks like this

```
$('#previous3Days').click(function () {

    var a = $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value();
    var d = $('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);

    $('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value(d);
    $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(a);
    if (a !== d) {
        $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(a);
        a.setDate(a.getDate() - 3);
    }
});
```

my problem is that the KendoComboBox don't change the value of the "Monthbis".

i tried every possibility like if (a>d) or (a!=d).

If i use (a>=d) every click both dates get changed.

i also checked the console in my browser according to this both dates are always the same and i don't see my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the logic of your program...

Changing `MonthVon` is ok since you (in order) you wrote:

```
var d = $('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value(); // Line 4
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);                             // Line 5
$('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value(d);        // Line 7
```

But for `MonthBis` the logic is pretty odd... This is what you wrote:

```
var a = $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(); // Line 3
$('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(a);        // Line 8
```

So you did nothing so far since you read and write the same value.

Then you check that a !== c and if so you do:

```
$('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(a);        // Line 10
a.setDate(a.getDate() - 3);                             // Line 11
```

You modify `a` but you do nothing with it's value so it actually does nothing.

Probably, you should swap lines 10 and 11 so you would have:

```
$('#previous3Days').click(function () {
    var d = $('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
    $('#MonthVon').data('kendoDatePicker').value(d);

    var a = $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value();
    if (a !== d) {
        a.setDate(a.getDate() - 3);
        $('#MonthBis').data('kendoDatePicker').value(a);
    }
});
```

Comment: i discovered another problem now it words great if both dates are different but if i have 2 x 20.09.2013 it still runs in the if.

But never mind my boss don't need the function anymore

thanks